# What causes an electron to return from a higher orbit to a lower orbit

Tags: energy, electrons, orbital-motion

Ultraviolet light can cause electrons from Hydrogen gas to jump from a lower energy orbit to a higher energy orbit. What causes the electrons to return from the higher energy orbit to the lower energy orbit by releasing photons? Would it be possible to maintain the electrons in the higher energy orbit? How? Would placing the hydrogen gas in an electric field generated between the parallel plates of a capacitor have this effect?

Comment: Spontaneous emission: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spontaneous_emission

Comment: It is worth mentioning the "[totalitarian principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Totalitarian_principle)" in this context: they can emit and photon and drop down so they do. All that remains is to compute the rate.

Comment: I'm also pretty sure we've had this question before, but I can't recall the title to find it...

Comment: Similar but not an exact duplicate: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/41591/